# Algorithm to minimize the 2-norm between two matrices

Tags: numerical-linear-algebra

What algorithm can you use to minimize the distance between two matrices? For example:

$$\min_{X \in \Gamma} \| A - X\|_2$$

$\Gamma$ all m $\times$ m rank $k$ matrices.

How can you think of this geometrically? If for least squares we minimize $Ax-b$ and look for $x$, but what vector do we look for in the difference between two matrices? I wish I could contribute more but I'm not really sure how to intrepret this.

Comment: You can rewrite this assuming a Singular Value Decomposition (SVD) on $X = U\Sigma V^*$ and another one on $A$. We can without lack of generality assume $\Sigma$ sorted along diagonal if we wish. How does rank translate into constraints on $\Sigma$?

Comment: This is related to [low-rank approximation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Low-rank_approximation).

Comment: SVD is how I was approaching it. Also I don't know the rank question.

Answer (score 1):

This corresponds to optimisation the cost function on the  [Grassmanian manifold](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Grassmannian). One can use the theory of [optimisation on manifolds](http://www.eeci-institute.eu/GSC2011/Photos-EECI/EECI-GSC-2011-M5/book_AMS.pdf). In particular, [reimannian gradient descent on Grassmanian manifolds](http://www.maths.lu.se/fileadmin/maths/personal_staff/johnsson/grassopt/Theory.pdf) provides an iterative algorithm.